# Cosmos DB trigger - Shared throughput collection should have a partition key

Tags: azure-functions, azure-cosmosdb

I have an Azure Function with a Cosmos DB trigger configured to auto-create a lease collection on-demand, I get the following error when running against a Cosmos DB with throughput configured at database level

> [30/11/2018 23:33:04] Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host: Error indexing method 'Functions.Foo'. Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.CosmosDB: Cannot create Collection Information for X in database Y with lease leases in database Y : Shared throughput collection should have a partition key

Works absolutely fine when the throughput is solely configured at container level. Also tried manually creating a lease collection and setting `id` as the partition key (given from my other DB it looked like all a lease has was an `id` / `ttl`) but then it complains about the PK not being provided.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**EDIT** : this is now supported with the version 3.0.3 of the `Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.CosmosDB` NuGet package. Tested and works fine with Azure Functions 2.0.

---

James, this is being supported soon, the PR is already being reviewed to add Partitioned Lease Collections, please see https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk-extensions/pull/520

At this moment the version of the Change Feed Processor library used in Azure Functions does not support partitioned lease collections, the latest version does, so part of that PR is updating the library dependency.

This is mostly common on Shared RU at the Database level.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up, any idea when it's likely to be merged? In the meantime, are we saying we effectively can't run triggers on a database with shared RU?

Comment: James, Shared Databases require the collections to be partitions, so yes, it is a current limitation. Merge ETA should be in January, as this is tied to other Azure components' deployment timeline.

Comment: @MatiasQuaranta Any news on this? Still planned for this month?

Comment: Yes, hopefully it can be merged / pushed this week.

Answer (score 3):

Please take a look at the Function [Output - configuration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-cosmosdb-v2#output---configuration) Please note that this is for version 2.0 of Azure Function bindings for Cosmos DB.

[image: Azure Cosmos DB bindings for Azure Functions 2.x]

Comment: Thanks Mike, clearly I've read the page too many times as I completely missed that! Are there any docs or advice on what would make a good PK for a lease table? I've no idea how many potential records it might contain.

Comment: Just to clarify as per @MatiasQuaranta's answer - despite it being in the documentation it doesn't yet work.

Comment: I will get you an update. There were some breaking changes to 2.0. I will look into this. What version of Azure Functions are you working with?

Comment: This appears to be already to roll-out but I have a question into the product group.

Comment: After the new year is what I have been communicated. I cannot get a firm date but the code is in fact complete and just the dependencies are needing to be updated.

Comment: thanks for the update. In the meantime I've just reverted back to using container-level throughput.